# What are the school holiday dates in South Africa

Tags: planning, south-africa, school-holidays

What are the school holiday dates in South Africa, which would then affect our plans to travel?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about holidays!

Comment: I am sure if you just typed the same thing in google and clicked the first search result you would have gotten your answer, and that would have been a lot easier than asking here.

Comment: Also, which province? From memory it differs in the Cape to say, Natal... but things may have changed.

Comment: Also take note that private schools are under no obligation to follow the state school's terms. There terms are often different than what is the case with the normal schools.

Answer (score 2):

The school holidays in South Africa differ from province to province, and from year to year.

Pretty much any google search for 'school holidays south africa' will bring it up, but for completeness, [Schoolterms.co.za](http://www.schoolterms.co.za/) shows the breakdown for the upcoming year.  I won't copy and paste the dates as that'd make it out of date in 12 months, but you can follow the link.